# How to set the background of a System.Windows.window in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I am working on a project that lets me create an UI. There is a Win-form app, that lets you design a form much like Visual Studio Win Forms, but its just more customized.

When the form is emulated, a System.Windows.window is launched, but that does not have any background. How do I set a background for the entire window? I can set the background in the form when I am making the UI, but when its run as a window, there is no background.

```
private void emulateToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.tabControl1.TabCount <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Design a UI first");
            return;
        }


        List<String> tempForms = new List<String>();
        //Emulator_Window is System.Windows.window type
        Emulator_Window wpfwindow = new Emulator_Window();
        ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wpfwindow);

        foreach (TabPage t in tabControl1.TabPages)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.UserControl p1 = (System.Windows.Forms.UserControl)GetDesignSurface(t);
            tempForms.Add(t.Text);
            System.Windows.Forms.UserControl bkp = p1;
            p1.Scale(new SizeF(1.0f / CurrentSF, 1.0f / CurrentSF));
            List<UIControl_Prop> tempProps = new List<UIControl_Prop>();
            foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control c in GetControls(p1))
            {
                tempProps.Add(ExtractProperties((BaseControl)c, t.Text));
            }
            //p1.Scale(new SizeF(CurrentSF, CurrentSF));

            wpfwindow.MainDict.Add(t.Text, new Emulator_Window.UIPropList(tempProps));
            wpfwindow.LandDict.Add(t.Text, p1.Height < p1.Width ? true : false);
        }

        //wpfwindow.FontPaths = UIFontManager.GetFontPaths();
        List<String> temp_fontURI_list = UIFontManager.GetFontPaths();
        List<String> fontURI_list = new List<String>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (String path in temp_fontURI_list)
        {
            String tempString = Path.GetFullPath(path);
            int offset = tempString.LastIndexOf("\\");
            tempString = tempString.Remove(offset);
            tempString += "\\#"+UIFontManager.GetFamilyNames()[i];
            fontURI_list.Add(tempString);
            i++;
        }
        wpfwindow.FontPaths = fontURI_list;
        wpfwindow.mForms = tempForms;
        wpfwindow.DeviceDict = this.deviceList;
        wpfwindow.CurrentDevice = this.CurrentDevice;
        ChangeScalingFactor(1.0f);

        wpfwindow.ShowDialog();

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is winforms? `System.Windows.Window` is a PresentationFramework class and your code even mentions "wpfwindow".

Comment: No, the tool was made using Winforms. The form has a colored background. It launches a System.Windows.Window `wpfwindow.ShowDialog()` to show the output which has no background.

Comment: In Visual studio, we create a winform and launch it using the Start button. here, the `emulateToolStripMenuItem_Click()` function is called as shown. I am a newbie. Any info will be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see *Emulator_Window* is a WPF window. You use it inside your WinForms application but still it is a WPF window. Even the name of the variable suggests that.

Knowing that we work with WPF it is quite easy to set the background. For example the following codes use a picture as the background:

```
wpfwindow.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(pathToThePicture)));
```

Here is an another example which fills the window with the solid blue color:

```
wpfwindow.Background = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Blue);
```